# How to avoid Man-In-The-App Hijacking in Android?

Tags: android, code-injection, man-in-the-middle

How to prevent the code injection using third party hacking tool using some libraries like faking data, manipulating data, de-facing, etc?

Using some third party tool/app it is possible to manipulate the data of the app. How to overcome/prevent this Hijacking of the app ?

I obfuscated the code, disabled the Emulator; still the third party tool is able to inject/modify some code of the app.

Comment: I think you can't do anything to prevent it, you can only make it harder with obfuscation

Comment: By default every member in a class is package private , declare every member variable in a class as private (if possible) so that if the tool injects some classes in the package it wont be able to access members of classes residing in that package.

Comment: @lelloman please research first rather than just saying you cant do anything , things i told has been considered good practices to prevent injection of code in packages